# Hierarchical SQL in one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a hierarchical SQL Server query but can't figure it out - here is the source table. I want to use a recursive CTE to figure out

ID, employee Name, Supervisor ID, hierarchy in one field i.e.

```
| 2 | Andreas Sitter | 1 | Heinz Grisser -> Andreas Sitter |
```

Source table

| ID | Name | Position | Department | Supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Heinz Griesser | IT Director | IT | 0 |
| 2 | Andreas Sitter | IT Security Manager | IT | 1 |
| 3 | Thomas Bergmann | IT Innovation Manager | IT | 1 |
| 4 | Hannes Berg | IT Operation Manager | IT | 1 |
| 5 | Anna Kruggel | Administrator | IT | 4 |
| 6 | Karin Pacher | Developer | IT | 4 |
| 7 | Patrick Wurzer | IT Service Manager | IT | 1 |
| 8 | Micheal Maier | Administrator | IT | 7 |
| 9 | David Fanzott | Developer | IT | 4 |
| 10 | Andrea Sternig | IT Architecture Manager | IT | 1 |
| 11 | Dominik Kainzner | Portfolio Engineer | IT | 10 |
| 12 | Luca Egarter | Requirement Engineer | IT | 10 |
| 13 | Hannes Maier | Developer | IT | 3 |
| 14 | Thomas Steiner | Administrator | IT | 3 |
| 15 | Andrea Huber | Requirement Engineer | IT | 10 |
| 16 | Jasmin Mentil | Developer | IT | 4 |
| 17 | Peter Schuller | Service Support Engineer | IT | 7 |
| 18 | Chris Feierabend | Service Support Engineer | IT | 7 |

My code

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        Name, 
        Supervisor,
        Name AS tree
    FROM employee 
    WHERE Supervisor = '0'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        emp.ID, 
        emp.Name,
        emp.Supervisor,
        CASE WHEN manager.ID = '0'
            THEN manager.Name
        ELSE 
            manager.Name +'->' + emp.Name
        END AS tree
    FROM employee emp
    INNER JOIN CTE as manager
    ON manager.ID = emp.Supervisor 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

For some reason I am not getting this tree field.

Comment: Please do not tag `MySQL` when asking for `SQL Server` code. `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not getting this tree field."? Is the query erroring, or returning unexpected results?

Comment: the problem is that you don't use the `tree` field when generating the manager tree, so you only get the last manager's name, change `manager.Name` to `manager.tree` in the recursive part of cte

Answer (score 1):

To produce the organizational chart with the management chain for each employee, use a recursive CTE :

```
WITH employee_hierarchy  (ID, Name, Supervisor, hierarchy) AS
(
  SELECT ID, Name, Supervisor, CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), Name)
    FROM employees
    WHERE Supervisor = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.ID, e.Name, e.Supervisor, CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), ep.hierarchy + ' > ' + e.Name)
    FROM employee_hierarchy  AS ep 
    JOIN employees AS e
      ON ep.ID = e.Supervisor
)
SELECT * FROM employee_hierarchy  
ORDER BY ID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/S6veSwop)

Comment: This isn't wokring on my dbeaver

Comment: Would you be able to answer using the format that i shared?

Comment: dbeaver is commonly used by mysql/mariadb ... Are you sure using SQL SERVER ?